# How can I post a bug in jira with httpclient once logged in?

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, hipchat

i am login in jira from this code now i want to post bug in jira after login

```js
     
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://id.atlassian.com/login?continue=https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa&application=jac");
 


        
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "sxxxxxxx@live.com"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxxxxxxxxn"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrfToken", xcrfTokenVal));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("continue", "https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/Dashboard.jsp"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("application", "jac"));
        
        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

           response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
 
        System.out.println("Response " + response.toString());
         entity = response.getEntity();
                //System.out.println("Double check we've got right page " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        System.out.println("Response from : " + response.getStatusLine());
```

After login i want to post bug from our tool to jira.... guys help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
Open google chrome 'developer tool' - >'Network'.
Then make a dump bug reporting via chrome.
You will see a new POST in the list, select it and check the detail of the post.
for example: cookie, post data, request URL.
Then simulate the same thing in Java code.
Login - > Send the post request.
```

Comment: Sir Jerry!   i am following this rule...... Send me your mail id plz.
<fieldset class="hidden parameters">
<input type="hidden" title="loggedInUser" value="sikandra">
<input type="hidden" title="ajaxTimeout" value="The call to the JIRA server did not complete within the timeout period.  We are unsure of the result of this operation."><input type="hidden" title="ajaxUnauthorised" value="You are not authorised to perform this operation. Please log in."> <input type="hidden" title="baseURL" value="https://jira.atlassian.com:443">
<input type="hidden" title="ajaxCommsError" value="The JIRA server

Comment: Send me email id i will send screen shot of error.. jerry sir i need your help